# Nginx WordPress and another Web app URL structure

Tags: php, url-rewriting, urls, seo, nginx

I have got WordPress installed on my root example.com/ Website.

Also I have another Web application that on example.com/my-app/ which has got ugly links like example.com/my-app/file.php?arg=value to access.

How can I make my-app SEO friendly URI structure working as example below?:

```
example.com/my-app/file.php?arg=value
to
example.com/my-app/value/
```

Currently, if I access to example.com/my-app/value/ it redirects me to my WordPress post which contains some characters of the /value/. Why? Is there anyway to get this working?

My Nginx directives for domain are listed below:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Any ideas? Should I use Ajax navigation, with switch cases? What about HTML5 pushState() API? Any working examples?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the [Rewrite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/) plugin as mentioned in this post "[Nginx rewrite rule conflict with WordPress permalinks rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/182123/34502)", it could help solve the issue. If not, we'll have to dig deeper, let me know.